# I have to choose twice on dual boot if I choose to boot Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop to dual-boot it with Windows 7 that has already been installed. Then I used EasyBCD to configure it. When I choose Windows 7 in the menu, it boots directly to Windows.
When I choose Ubuntu, however, GRUB2 screen appears and I have to choose Ubuntu again.
How can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `/etc/default/grub`, change `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to `0` (i.e., zero)

Then `update-grub`, that should fix it.

Regards